# Error importing TestCafe 't' object in Angular 13 TypeScript compilation failure due to case sensitivity issue

Tags: angular, testcafe

I'm encountering an issue while working with Angular 13 and TestCafe 3.4.0. When attempting to import the 't' object from TestCafe using the statement import { t } from 'testcafe';, I encounter the following error:

ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to the following error:

Error: TypeScript compilation failed.
C:/path/path/projectName/e2e/src/importLine(1, 19): File name 'C:/path/path/projectName/node_modules/testcafe/ts-defs/index.d.ts' differs from already included file name 'c:/path/path/projectName/node_modules/testcafe/ts-defs/index.d.ts' only in casing.

It seems like there's an issue related to file paths and case sensitivity within the node_modules directory.

I tried to:
-Deleted the node_modules directory and reinstalled dependencies using npm install.
-Attempted to change the versions of TestCafe to see if the issue persists across different versions.

If you have any ideas or tips to help fix this, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Hello,

Please create a ticket using this [template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) and share a [Minimal Working Example](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402636/faq/general-info?search#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue) in that ticket so that the TestCafe team can research the issue and help you.